# Problem showing datagridview values 0 and null with CellPainting

Tags: c#, datagridview, null, zero

https://prnt.sc/ou2tvv

Hi, excuse me, I don't have much experience.
I found a code.
To this I added the datatable, empty.
And when I run it, it doesn't show me values in the datagridview.
The code I found on the web does not work well for null and 0 values.
Can anyone help me with this.
Thanks for your help.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private StringFormat m_sf;

        private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex < 0)
                return;
            if (e.ColumnIndex < 0)
                return;
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
                return;
            if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "pct")
            {
                e.Handled = true;

                LinearGradientBrush brocha;
                decimal max = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Max(dr => System.Convert.ToDecimal(dr.Cells["total"].Value));
                decimal val = System.Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["total"].Value);
                Rectangle r = e.CellBounds;

                r.Width = System.Convert.ToInt32(r.Width * val / (decimal)max);
                if (r.Width > 0)
                {
                    brocha = new LinearGradientBrush(r, Color.WhiteSmoke, Color.Green, 90);
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.WhiteSmoke, e.CellBounds);
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brocha, r);
                }
                e.Graphics.DrawString(System.Convert.ToInt32(val).ToString(), Font, Brushes.Black, e.CellBounds, m_sf);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataTable dgv1 = GetTable();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dgv1;

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("total", "Total");
            dataGridView1.Columns["total"].ValueType = typeof(decimal);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("pct", "Porcentaje");
            dataGridView1.Columns["pct"].ReadOnly = true;

            m_sf = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Far, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };
        }

        static DataTable GetTable()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dgv1 = new DataTable();
            ds.Tables.Add(dgv1);

            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                dgv1.Rows.Add();

            }
            return dgv1;
        }
    }
}
```

https://prnt.sc/ou2v65

The code works if the datagridview has values, but if there are null or zero values it does not work well.

Comment: I attached a link to an image, I don't know if this is allowed.

Comment: You need do `e.Handled = true;` in other if blocks too.

Comment: Add a `null` or `0` check: `if (val != null && val != 0) {... Draw your stuff }` - currently if `r.Width` is 0 it won't do anything which it will be if `val` is 0.

Comment: Sorry in what block you say?

Answer (score 1):

> The code works if the datagridview has values, but if there are null or zero values it does not work well.

The following code will produce `DivideByZeroException` due to `max` being 0 when there are no rows or their maximum value is 0:

```cs
r.Width = System.Convert.ToInt32(r.Width * val / (decimal)max);
```

Comment: Thank you very much everyone for your help, I will use another code, and I will try to adapt it.